# Regex: Replace last space, nothing after

Tags: regex

Regex:

```
/\s+\S*$/
```

String:

```
Learn more about the Ministry of Magic
```

Using http://www.regexpal.com/ I am trying to get ONLY the last space. But the above regex gets the last space and everything after that's not a space. How do I ONLY get the last space??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a positive lookahead that only checks if its pattern matches without putting the matched text into the returned match value:

```
\s+(?=\S*$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kURg2a/1)

**Details**:

- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespace chars
- `(?=\S*$)` - a positive lookahead requiring that there must be 0+ non-whitespace chars immediately to the right of the current location followed with the end of string position.